# How can I disable/delete all history in VLC media player?

Tags: linux, vlc-media-player

I'm using VLC media player 2.2.1 with the Qt interface (i.e. the default one) in Linux (Xubuntu 15.10).

In the preferences, I have disabled history. However, in the 'Open File...' dialogue, in the 'Look in:' menu, under the 'Recent Places' heading, there's still a list of all of the directories that were last opened in VLC.

Entries remain in this list even after the corresponding directories have been deleted.

Obviously this list is stored somewhere in my home directory, so I searched within every file in my home directory for one of the directory names, by using `grep -ri`, but there were no matches. I also looked in `~/.local/share/recently-used.xbel`.

So where is this list stored, and how can I either disable the creation of it, or delete it?

Comment: Not sure if this is an option - what about Bleachbit? http://www.bleachbit.org/download/linux  I know that Ccleaner should have it as well - but, is Windows.

Answer (score 7):

Found the answer at the following link:
http://www.ghacks.net/2013/05/12/how-to-disable-vlc-media-players-open-recent-media-feature/

1. Click on Tools > Preferences in the top menu or use the shortcut Ctrl-P to open the preferences.
2. While in the Interface section here, locate the Save recently played items option on the page.
3. Uncheck the box to disable the logging of played videos.
4. Click on the save button.

Note that you do need to restart VLC before the change takes effect. You will notice that the menu is no longer displayed under Media. You can re-enable it by following the same steps outlined above.

Disabling the feature does not clear the list. If you re-enable the list, you see the videos that have been accessed before it was disabled. So, use the clear option first before you disable it

Comment: Thank you for your effort. Sadly you seem to have misunderstood the question. I said that I have already disabled history in the preferences. I'm talking about the history of recently opened directories in the 'Open' dialogue; not the recently opened files in the 'File' menu.

Comment: Even if this does not answer OP's question it did mine. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I came across the same issue that you faced and I managed to overcome it by following steps

If you right-click the VLC icon on your Taskbar, you will still see a couple of watched videos listed there, too. Here’s how to get rid of those:

1. Right-click an empty space on your desktop and select “Personalize.”
2. Select “Start” and find “Show recently opened items in Jump Lists on Start or the
   taskbar.”
3. Toggle it to “Off” and close the window.

[image: screenshot]

***Be aware that if you use the jump list in other apps, they will no longer work as this is a universal setting.***

Comment: I was refering to the history of recently opened directories in the 'Open' dialogue in Linux.